# Download and Install IntelliJ in Windows 32 bit OS

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am trying to IntelliJ in Windows 7 32 bit OS  based on documentation.

I downloaded IntelliJ latest. And tried to install it saying "it does not work for 32 bit."

I read a statement that

> JRE for 32-bit systems is not bundled with IntelliJ IDEA. If you are using a 32-bit version of Windows, select the Download and install JRE x86 by JetBrains checkbox in the installation wizard.

But I am not getting any wizard.

Comment: Please share the IntelliJ download link and the error message

Answer (score 5):

IntelliJ IDEA [2018.3.6](https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIU-2018.3.6.exe?_ga=2.47016871.1424988563.1577291372-1484722978.1577291372) precisely supports 32-bit Windows OS (checked on Windows 7 x86). 
I've also checked version 2019.3.1 (.exe and .zip) but it supports 64-bit systems only.

Answer (score 4):

Download a version on IntelliJ Idea with bundled JBR8 from the other versions page of the [Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html) website.

Answer (score 3):

Download an older version of IntelliJ. They have [other versions](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/other.html) available. Read the release notes and find the one that suits your requirements. The 2017 release should work. You will have to manually install the JDK package though. There's a [discussion](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000437424-IDEA-Community-Edition-2017-1-5-won-t-start-Win-7-32-bit) on that. To be completely honest, support for Windows 7 has almost completely faded out on all applications, since it is now considered obsolete. Check if Eclipse/BlueJ satisfies your requirements. You might also want to try deleting all the IntelliJ software and restarting your computer, then go through the download process carefully.

[BlueJ v 4.1.4](https://www.bluej.org/versions.html) supports 32-bit systems. Most IDEs now work with Java 11 and beyond, and Java 11 itself requires 64-bit systems. As the BlueJ website states, over 95% of users have a 64-bit system now, so 32-bit is a waste of development resources.

Comment: Do you know which is the last (latest) version that works on 32-bit Windows?

Comment: Added link, and more info. Accept the answer by clicking on the check mark, and the answer author will get to know that no further edits are required.

Answer (score 1):

Download 2017.2.7 version of idea to have 32 bit launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue ,downloaded zip file of intellij which contains 32 bit runtime (2019.3 for Windows ZIP Archive (zip)) instead of installer file

Answer (score 0):

use idea64.exe instead of idea.exe
No need to modify any thing.

Path: IntelliJ_Home\bin\idea64.exe

example:
C:\abhietc\installation\id\ideaIC-2021.1.2.win\bin\idea64.exe

Comment: That executable is for 64 bit only...

Answer (score 0):

Use IntelliJ IDEA with JBR 8
for example [2019.3.1 - Windows with Bundled JBR 8 (exe)](https://download.jetbrains.com/idea/ideaIC-2019.3.1-jbr8.exe?_gl=1*ifrq4u*_ga*MTI5MjkxODA4OC4xNjY1MTU3MTU4*_ga_9J976DJZ68*MTY2NTQ2NDk4OC4yLjEuMTY2NTQ2NjIwOS4wLjAuMA..&_ga=2.195234410.716527618.1665464988-1292918088.1665157158)